# @metamask/detect-provider cant use request function

Tags: metamask

I want to connect Metamask on the web-browser using ReactJS

provider from @metamask/detect-provider doesnt have request function.

How can I use request function ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use web3-react library from npm it will allow you to connect with the metamask make sure you have metamask installed in your browser

Comment: I used it. It did not work on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you should write it inside an `if` statement

```
if(provider){
    provider.request({})
}
```

Comment: typescript says there is no request function in provider type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961190/property-ethereum-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis-error/72081301#72081301